# Microservice Messaging

Tags: events, rabbitmq, event-handling, microservices, message-queue

If i have a generic service, like an email service which sends emails based on events from other services, which one of these approaches would be best:

1. Email service listens to multiple queues/specific events and sends emails once those events trigger. For example email service listens to `users_queue` and sends a welcome email on `user_created` event.
2. Have a generic email queue to which multiple services can emit a generic `send_email` event. Another note on this approach: what if other services, apart from the email service, want to listen to events from this service? Should i emit two events, one to the email queue and one to a queue specific for this service and have those other services implement the first approach?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, you are asking whether you should adopt an Orchestration or Choreography based approach:

- Service Orchestration refers to an imperative coordination style, here imperative coordination referring to a sequence of instructions with explicit control and data flow.
- Service Choreography refers to a declarative coordination style, here declarative coordination referring to a set of instructions with implicit control and data flow.

Alternative #1 details a Choreography based approach, the Email service reacts to a set of *Events* types on a set of queues, here one event type `user_created` on the queue `users_queue`

Alternative #2 details an Orchestration based approach, the Email service reacts to one *Command* type on one queue, here the command type `send_email` on the queue `email_queue`

When choosing an approach, consider this:

Email service require a set of input arguments like recipient address, subject line, email template, and template data.

So if you choose a Choreography based approach, *every* event that the Email service reacts to must provide (information to retrieve) the required arguments - In fact *every* event must provide all (information to retrieve) the required arguments for *all* services that react to the event.

To your last question if you should emit the same event to multiple queues:

Consider emitting the event once and have the eventing middleware take care of managing subscriptions and/or event routing